# c# block matching on two 2d Lists

Tags: c#, vector, pattern-matching, signal-processing

I am a bit puzzled. How would one go about implementing an exaustive block search (motion vectors) on two 2d Lists.

Data that we have:

```
List<List<float>> oldFrame; //both sized 512 x 512
List<List<float>> newFrame;
```

Assuming that the search window is 16x16 and the kernel is 8x8 I can picture what has to happen but just can't seem to translate it into code. It doesn't help that there are no examples in languages other than MATLAB.